# Command "tree -J" returns invalid Json

Tags: tree

I gave the command `tree -J` to my machine, and this is a portion of the output it gave:

```
                {
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "ca-certificates.conf"
                },
                {
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "ca-certificates.conf.dpkg-old"
                },
                {
                    "type": "directory",
                    "name": "chatscripts"
                } {
                    "error": "error opening dir"
                },
                {
                    "type": "directory",
                    "name": "chromium",
                    "contents": [{
                        "type": "directory",
                        "name": "native-messaging-hosts"
                    }]
                }
```

Have a look at that "error" node: it does not appear to be valid Json (a `,` is missing). How can I avoid the displaying of such errors?

Using `v2.0.2`

Comment: seems to be aknown bug, see https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/issues/11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a known bug](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/issues/11).
Apparently it was fixed *yesterday*, 2023-05-31.

I'm not seeing where in https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/commit/84fa3ddff51b30835a0f9c4a9e4c9225970f9aff it was fixed, but this is between you and [Steve Baker](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/).

Comment: I guess there are multiple invalid JSON bugs lurking around. The one about the error and missing comma was fixed in [2.0.4 (09/06/2022)](https://gitlab.com/OldManProgrammer/unix-tree/-/commit/c70f1b9adbe98016b658e25b05978905f3f85d92)  by adding the missing comma.